# How do i create recurring teams meeting on Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, meetings

I have to create a meeting that would occur each Tuesday for a while, I could Create a recurring meeting in a series but the issue is each meeting has to have different titles and different attendees. is there any way I could create for all the coming weeks in one go rather than creating each one by one and adding attendees.

it would be great if there is any way where i could save a little time

Thanks!

Comment: You can’t create a recurring meeting that has a different title week to week. How you create an event, with the same name, that will happen (daily, weekly, monthly, ect.) is well documented otherwise

Comment: As Ramhound says this isn't a recurring meeting, it's just a lot of meetings that happen at the same time. Recurring meetings would have all the same people and the same title. What you want is to create different meetings in bulk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/69384/teams-meeting-links-bulk-creation seems to have an option using Power Automate and a spreadsheet but doesn't add attendees, otherwise Googling https://www.google.com/search?q=teams+bulk+create+meeting gives other possibilities.